# How to exclude my featured post from all posts loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

In my view, I have 2 section where I'm passing a featured post and all posts respectively. The issue I'm having is trying to remove the featured post from the all posts sections since it already being displayed in it's own unique container. Second question that ties in with the first, if I were to create another post and make it featured, how would I make the post that was last featured default to a normal post i.e 0 = normal post, 1 = featured post

Index View

```
//Featured post
@foreach ($featuredPosts as $featured)
 <a href="/posts/{{$featured->id}}">
  <img src="{{ asset('assets/frontend/img/beach.jpg') }}" class="featured-post-img">
     <figcaption class="article-title-container">
       <div class="position-absolute article-tag">
         <span class="text-white tag-blue">{{ $featured->tags }}</span>
       </div>
       <div class="position-relative">
        <h1 class="article-title text-dark">{{ $featured->title }}</h1>
       </div>
     </figcaption>
    @endforeach

//All posts
@foreach ($allPosts as $post)
 <div class="col-xl-12">
  <div class="row g-3 mb-2">
   <div class="col-xl-6">
    <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}"><img src="{{ asset('assets/frontend/img/midoriya.jpg') }}"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 related-posts-heading">
     <a href=""><p class="text-dark">{{ $post->title }}</p></a>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Post Controller

```
// Show all listings
public function index(Request $request) {
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
   $allPosts = Posts::latest()->get();
   $paginate = Posts::latest()->paginate(6);
   $featuredPosts = $allPosts->filter(function($query) {
        return $query->featured == true;
    });
    return view('frontend.posts.index', compact('allPosts', 'featuredPosts', 'paginate'));
}

Posts::create([
 'title' => $request->post('title'),
 'sub_title' => $request->post('sub_title'),
 'tags' => $request->post('tags'),
 'content' => $request->post('content'),
 'featured' => ($request->has('featured')) ? true : false,
]);
```

Comment: `<img src="{{ asset('assets/frontend/img/beach.jpg') }}" featured-post-img">` contains a trailing `"` that shouldn't be there. Are you missing `class="` before `featured-post-img`?

Comment: Yep, my bad. The trailing " was from a missing class. Thanks

Comment: Something like `Posts::where('featured', false)->get()` and `Posts::where('featured', true)->first()` (assuming that you only have _one_ featured post) should get you nonfeatured/featured posts. (Unrelated fyi: you can name your model whatever you want, but it usually takes the singular form, `Post` in your case)

Comment: Bit confused if you may please clarify, should I append that to my $allPosts?. As for the naming convention, thanks for the tip. Excuse me if my code is a bit messy i've not been studying laravel very long

Comment: Unless you really want to show all posts somewhere you could remove `$allPosts`. Getting all posts, then filtering them to get _one_ post is not very efficient. (You might get 100000 posts only to return one post in the end). `$paginate` would be `Posts::where('featured', false)->paginate(6)`. Personally I would rename `$featuredPosts` to `$featuredPost` (since it is only _one_ post). Then, `$featuredPost = Posts::where('featured', true)->first()` would get you only the _one_ post that is featured (more efficient)

Comment: Yea looping through a whole table to find one featured post is not very smart. It helped a lot. It worked well. The next question is what can I use on my view instead of a forEach loop for my featured post since every featured post will end up being displayed every time I create a featured post. Ideally I would like that the featured post would become a normal post (switches to 0), while the new featured will become 1.

Comment: Basically, before your `Posts::create(...)` you need to check if `$request->post('featured')` is set/true, then update all Posts that have `featured=true` to `featured=false`. The documentation has examples for model [Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#updates). (Note, since you only have _one_ featured post there is no need to `foreach` your featured post in your view, you can directly access the `$featuredPost`)

Comment: Never thought all my questions would answered but thank you so much for your help and explanations :D